# "less cheap" Vs. "less cheaper"

Tags: adjectives

If I see two products that are cheap, for example, if normally each product costs $10 and now one of them (**product A**) costs $5 and the second (**product B**) costs $7. Then what will be the correct form to refer to **product B** price state?

- *Choice 1*: Product B is less cheap.
- *Choice 2*: Product B is less cheap**er**. (with comparative form)

Now it's obvious that I can use in terms of expensive (for product B) and cheaper (for product A), but my question deals with a situation in which I'd like to emphasis or to focus on the cheapness (since in the end of the day they're both cheaper than normal).

Is it valid at all in English to use one of these couple of words: "**less cheap**" or "**less cheaper**"?

Comment: _Product B is more expensive; Product A is cheaper._

Comment: It is understood, but if I'd like to emphasis or to focus on the cheapness that means that I can't use one of the choices at all?

Comment: Just for the record, if an adjective has two syllables or less, we add er for the comparative. less and more are used with longer ones (three syllables): less interesting, more interesting, more expensive, less expensive. But cheaper and funnier. Therefore, one would write/say: Product A is less expensive or cheaper. [ELL link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/use-of-er-or-the-word-more-to-make-comparative-forms).

Comment: Intriguingly, I didn't think [this](https://www.google.com/search?q="less%20cheaper"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd) is grammatical. English never cease to amaze me! 

..

Comment: I left that as a comment instead of an answer because I think both forms sound a little awkward. I’ll let an answerer address your question more directly.

Comment: The use of "39% less cheaper than" is very specific in those economics books. It's a kind of short-hand used by the author. In general, it would not be right.

Comment: Please note the parse in that book cited by Lucian Sava: [...] 27 percent indicated "they would buy the rayon if it were 19 percent or less cheaper than cotton, and 87 percent said they would switch if the price of the rayon shirt were 39 percent or less cheaper than the corresponding cotton shirt (tables 35,36)" That is correct: if x is some percent or less cheaper than. The word percent makes it grammatical.

Comment: @J.R. so basically you're saying that such couple of words "less cheap" or "less cheaper" are awkward while Lambie is saying that are not valid. Isn't it? If so, how can you explain that "much cheaper" is widely in usage? ("much" as far as I understand, is the antonym of "less")

Comment: @LucianSava - I changed your search to only include results from the past 35 years, and there were [very few](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22less+cheaper%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1970,cd_max:2005&tbm=bks&start=10&sa=N&biw=1612&bih=918&dpr=1), and many of those were false hits (such as when one sentence ends with the word _less_ and the next sentence begins with the word _cheaper_). We can debate whether this phrase is incorrect, awkward, nonstandard, or ungrammatical, but the point is, it should probably be avoided most of the time.

Comment: @Archimedean_Point A is more or less cheaper than B=means something else. It is not a comparative: This is more or less interesting. More or less in English means: somewhat cheaper, somewhat interesting.

Comment: @Lambie I deleted my comment there because it was my mistake. I understood it. What I brought is not a proof as you noted. I don't want to mislead other readers with my mistake.

Comment: @LucianSava In that economics text, it is not awkward or wrong. It is not saying: A is "less cheaper" than B. It is saying: if X percentage were |39 percent or less| [as a percent] cheaper than.

Comment: What's about "less cheap"? https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=rb3cWoOyLI_ewQKK7b3ICg&q=%22less+cheap%22&oq=%22less+cheap%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19986.19986.0.20265.1.1.0.0.0.0.217.217.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.LWfgQfN7bAA

Comment: @Archimedean_Point - Basically, yes. Lambie often categorizes something as “wrong” or “incorrect” while I ofter prefer to call it “awkward” or “unusual” or “rare”. Exceptions abound in English; the expression “less cheap” might work just fine in a problem found in an Economics textbook, or in a travel guide, but we both agree that, more often than not, “cheaper” will work better than “less cheap”.

Comment: Cheap is not only price. If you say Product A is less cheap. It can mean: ***Product A is higher quality***. When talking about COST, people say: Product A is cheaper [than product B] or Product B is more expensive than Product B. And I would never say at the level we are talking about (comparatives) "X is less cheaper than B", in that kind of utterance. Who would say that?? So, yes, never use that or you will sound weird. [ha  ha, joke, if I am permitted to make one.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**X is cheaper than Y**. [X =10, Y=20]

**X is less expensive than Y**. [X=10, Y=20]

Those two sentences mean the same thing.

**Conversely, Y is more expensive than X**.

Cheap, one syllable, just add ER: Cheap=cheaper

Expensive, **three syllables**, **add less or more**: less expensive than, more expensive than.

In fact, X is **much cheaper** than Y, by 10 dollars. Much=an adverb that modifies cheaper.

much cheaper is an adverb and goes with cheaper.  It is not **a little cheaper**, it is **a lot** cheaper. much cheaper=a lot cheaper.

Adding much or a lot or a little [adverbs] to a comparative is fine.

Much cheaper, but:  much more expensive.

The other meaning of CHEAP=BAD quality:

Product A is less cheap than Product B= The quality of Product A is higher than the quality of Product B.

Comparative: Product A looks less cheap than Product B.

Comment: If "**much** cheaper" is OK then **a little bit** cheaper is also OK. The problem is just with **more** and **less** cheaper. Did I get you?

Comment: @subtle_sibling Yes, more and less cheaper is out except for the kind of example given in that economics book, which in fact does not parse as suggested....

Answer (score 1):

> Choice 1: Product B is less cheap. 
>   Choice 2: Product B is less cheaper.

Of these choices, only (1) is possible. Choice (2) is immediately ruled out because we cannot combine a comparative adverb (less/more) with a comparative adjective (cheaper).

Comment: And what's your opinion about choice (1)? Do you agree with the other answer here on the page?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question but I end up saying that there is no grammatical mistake in using ***less*** with short or long adjectives and with ***—er*** or no ***—er***. Because ***less*** and ***more*** function as adverbs used to modify adjectives, adverbs and verbs.

On the other hand, in comparative sentences, we have to respect its rules, so you would get points or not, the administrators could protect themselves with the rule and formulas of comparative form, when to use ***less*** and ***more*** and when they are not allowed.